# Wifi not showing any networks

Tags: wireless, 18.04, network-manager

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:08a6]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
```

**Any solution to this problem? I am using an acer laptop which came pre-installed windows 10**

Comment: I would do `sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` Then reboot

Comment: Tried it. No change after reboot.